# How to change the color temperature in games on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, f.lux

I used to use Windows XP and used the program [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to change my color temperature to my preference. The program also changed the color temperature when running games.

I upgraded to Windows 7 and while f.lux still changes the color temperature in the desktop, it stopped changing it in games, which stay at the default color temperature. I want the games to also run in my preferred color temperature. Is there any solution? (doesn't matter if it's f.lux or a setting or another program)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes f.lux has trouble adjusting the screen color when playing games in fullscreen mode. If you adjust your game settings to run in either ***Windowed*** or ***Borderless Windowed*** mode, f.lux should work just fine.